# How to make the list item inside the ordered list inside a circle?

Tags: html

Are there list items in HTML that have the numbers inside circles? I could not find any such existing list item. I am also looking for a way to remove the dots after the numbers as well. Are there any special list items in HTML for ordered lists that I need to look for?

```html
<ol>
  <li>Mix flour, baking powder, sugar, and salt.</li>
  <li>In another bowl, mix eggs, milk, and oil.</li>
  <li>Stir both mixtures together.</li>
  <li>Fill muffin tray 3/4 full.</li>
  <li>Bake for 20 minutes.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image

Comment: See [`@counter-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style) and [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)

Comment: I think you want either https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/symbols() or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style - but yeah, support not great.

Answer (score 2):

```css
ol {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  list-style-type: none; /* remove default */
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: step-counter;  /*set it back */
  margin: 10px;  /* add margin to it */
}

ol li::before {
   /* use before to style it */
  content: counter(step-counter);
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  border-radius: 90px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Mix flour, baking powder, sugar, and salt.</li>
  <li>In another bowl, mix eggs, milk, and oil.</li>
  <li>Stir both mixtures together.</li>
  <li>Fill muffin tray 3/4 full.</li>
  <li>Bake for 20 minutes.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  counter-reset: circle-counter;
}

ol li {
  counter-increment: circle-counter;
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counter(circle-counter);
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
ol li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

For more details: you should visit this link.
https://codepen.io/mercuryworks/pen/ENEKEE